# Hide filter box angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to enable filtering in my grid however I do not want the user to input a value to filter on. Is there a way to hide the filter box for user input? Alternatively is there another way of enabling filtering in the ui-grid?

Answer (score 3):

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering

ng-grid has been rewritten as ui-grid and The filter field can be pre-populated by setting

```
filter: { term: 'xxx' } in the column def
```

in the column options declaration.  Alternativeliy, ng-grid has a similar setting in the column options declaration

```
FilterOptions   { filterText: '', useExternalFilter: false }
```

filterText: The text bound to the built-in search box. useExternalFilter: Bypass internal filtering if you want to roll your own filtering mechanism but want to use builtin search box

Comment: I have pre-populated the filter using the noterm option. That is why I want to hide the filter box in the grid. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it through CSS?

```
.ui-grid-filter-container {
  display: none;
}
```

It looks okay to me and doesn't leave any blank space below the column header.

Comment: This is great, but it would be nice if there were an option to shut it off.  Normally, I would say too many options isn't great, but since `ui-grid` doesn't seem to worry about having 90 trillion configuration options, what's one more?

Comment: This is great until you use the selection add-on and then have to set the selection box header's height.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: false
}
```

with this code you'll have no filters 
in the header

Comment: And won't it also not apply them?  I have a scenario where I want to hide the filter criteria, but still have them applied.